# Getting results from PHP after POSTING in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to learn how to use POST and GET stuff with PHP and Objective-c .

I came across a problem., after I make the  POST in objective-c , how do I get the return result?

My PHP file is:

```
<html>
<head><title>Bug Reporter</title></head>
<body>
<h2>Fancy Bug Reporter</h2>
<hr />
<?php
if (isset($_POST['go']))
{
        // Form was posted
        print "User submitted bug: ". $_POST['name'] . ": " . $_POST['description'];
}
else
{
        // Form was not posted, display form
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>">
Bug Name:<br /><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" /><br />
Bug Description:<br /><input type="text" name="description" maxlength="1000" size="80" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Add Bug">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

In objective-c :

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =
    [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
     [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxx.com/xxx.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *postString = @"go=1&name=Bad%20Bad%20Bug&description=This%20bug%20is%20really%20really%20super%20bad.";

    [request setValue:[NSString
                       stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]]
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[postString
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [[NSURLConnection alloc]
     initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: [That's how.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods, which will be called for any network connection event related to your request, such as authentication, failure, success, data received and so on.

Also I would suggest you to take a look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), a great networking library that wraps `NSURLConnection` providing block-based methods.

If find it much more convient than the plain `NSURLConnection` way.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but the answer is fine IMHO.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either, but if something it's wrong I'd like to know what is it, in order to fix it.

Comment: because I dont see why that is answer. it surely is good advice. the problem is rather (As I see it) that the request object isnt assigned and never started. -- BUT so everybody is happy ill remove my downvote anyways

Comment: I was giving for granted that the he started the connection... The question is about how to receive back the data and the natural answer is to use the delegate methods. Feel free to downvote me but I think you are mistaken in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

you never save the connection and fail to start it.
use the new convenience method:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse*r, NSData*d, NSError*e) { 
     ...
 }
```